# CakePHP bootstrap modal to save data in DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I have a problem. I'm new in Web Development, so I need help.
I have a project in CakePHP, in one "edit" view, I have a bootstrap modal, with which I need to save data in the database. Graphically and already all done, I just need to know how to do to save the data from the inputs, and send them through the modal, without reloading the page.

```
<div id="add" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><?= t('Dodaj wariant') ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= $this->Html->input('page_action' , [
                        'type' => 'hidden', 
                        'value' => f_eas('Subscriptions|update_variant')
                    ]) ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="subscription_id" value="<?= (int)$subscription->id ?>">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label><?= t('Cena') ?></label>
                        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="price" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label><?= t('Ważna od') ?></label>
                        <input type="text" name="valid_from" class="form-control datepicker" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label><?= t('Ważna do') ?></label>
                        <input type="text" name="valid_to" class="form-control datepicker" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label><?= t('Czas trwania') ?></label>
                        <input type="number" step="1" name="duration" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <?php $this->Form->unlockField('active'); ?>
                        <?= Html::getInstance()->toggle('active', ['checked' => $v->active, 'label' => t('Aktywny')]) ?>                            
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><?= t('Dodaj wariant') ?></button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default force-submit" value="<?= t('Wyślij') ?>">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this modal in my Edit.ctp.
What now ?

Comment: `ajax` can help you.

Comment: Yes, I know, but how ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/